# Android ViewPager: Call onStop() to set ExoPlayer instance to null

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, exoplayer

I am looking for a solution for my project, where I am working with ViewPager2, and I need some way to call `onStop()` when the user swipes, and I want to set ExoPlayer instance to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing a interface OnPageChangeListener and overriding its methods, There is method onPageSelected(position: Int) this method will be triggered when page change so you can compare position of your page and put you logic for your ExoPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:-

1. Register viewpager page change callback:

   ```
      viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(doppelgangerPageChangeCallback)
   ```
2. Set pageChangeCallback listener:

   ```
         var pageChangeCallback = object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
         override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
           releasePlayer()
         }    }
   ```

3.Function to initialize and release player below:

```
        fun initializePlayer() {
             player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
             playerView.setPlayer(player);
        }

        fun releasePlayer() {
          if (player != null) {
            player.release();
            player = null;
          }
        }
```